# How to call one portlet from another portlet in Liferay?

Tags: java, jsp, liferay-6, portlet

I have created 3 portlets (testimonial portlet, directory portlet, polling portlet), and I want to call **testimonial portlet** from **directory** portlet. How to do this? Kindly help me.

I have written the following code in my *view.jsp* file of directory portlet:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/portlet" prefix="liferay-portlet" %>

<liferay-portlet:renderURL var="linkURL" portletName="testi" windowState="maximized" />
<br>
<a href="<%= linkURL%>">Testimonial</a>
```

I can redirect in another page, but I got error like

> This portlet has been undeployed. Please redeploy it or remove it from
>   the page.

Should I make changes in *liferay-portlet.xml*? Kindly help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

portletName  attribute value , you specified seems incorrect.
Thats the reason, you are getting that message.
I just checked giving incorrect name "test" as portletName whereas there isnt any portlet with name test.

If `<portlet-name>test</portlet-name>` is the entry in your liferay-portlet.xml ,
then give portletName as **test_WAR_testportlet**, it will work.

If other portlet is Liferay's Out of Box portlet, you can utilize PortletKeys class.

HTH

Comment: how to get excet portlet name?

Comment: what should i write instead of "testi" kindly tell me

Comment: If `<portlet-name>test</portlet-name>` is the entry in your liferay-portlet.xml , then give portletName as test_WAR_testportlet, it will work.

If other portlet is Liferay's Out of Box portlet, you can utilize PortletKeys class.

Answer (score 0):

I had same requirement. But i am very new in Liferay...
So i have not much more knowledge of Liferay API.

So I used web service for fetch portlet data to another portlet. Its really interesting and very easy..

You can find more help from this.

[Jersey RestFul webService](http://www.liferay.com/web/pradip.bhatt/blog/-/blogs/integrate-jersey-restful-with-portlet-project?_33_redirect=http://www.liferay.com/web/pradip.bhatt/blog?p_p_id=33&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-2&p_p_col_count=1)

I done this and all working very well.

Thankssssss